# vector<int*>.push_back() is overwriting values pointed to by front()

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stdvector, overwrite

The code is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UknqKvMq

So, I'm permuting all possible arrangements of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (ie, forming 10-digit numbers). I am storing each arrangement on the heap by calling

```
new int[10]
```

the pointer that is returned I push onto a

```
static vector<int*>
```

Now, when I push a pointer onto the vector, the data pointed to by the first item is being modified (and maybe all other items pointed to by the vector). I have a number of print statements in the code showing this, with sleep() calls to slow the process down. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why use integer "arrays" in the first place, why not use vectors all throughout?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Habit I suppose.

Comment: @john Explain? I'm comfortable with pointers and see no problem.

Comment: @FluidicTapestry I'll bet a pound to a penny that the error is caused by pointer use.

Comment: @john But how exactly? Please be constructive with you comments.

Comment: @FluidicTapestry I've just run your code. It looks like the problem is that you free a pointer after you have pushed it onto your vector. Programming is easier without pointers, save them for the times they are really needed. Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of `std::vector<int*>`.

Comment: @John *facepalm* Yup, you're right. I copied the permutation code and modified it slightly (it used to COPY the arrangment array), resulting in the delete causing my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @FluidicTapestry I think the lesson is that all that work you are doing copying blocks of memory around would all be done for you if you used standard containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Permute`, which pushes the pointer `inputCopy->arrangement` into your static vector. Then immediately afterwards you delete it. This means your vector contains dangling pointers.

Comment: Thanks! Someone else pointed this out as well. Silly mistake, I copied the permutation code and modified it slightly (it used to copy the arrangement array).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to do here, but you can write that up in few lines of code:

Using [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
// std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
do {

    for(const auto&i:v)
      std::cout<<i;
    std::cout<<std::endl;

} while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

Comment: is the sort at the start even necessary?

Comment: @PreetKukreti noop, just commented, out

Comment: I'm not interested in optimising the number of lines of code, but to solve my memory issue.

Comment: @FluidicTapestry cool, good luck, surely you'll get some nice answers

Comment: @FluidicTapestry I think you need some more memcpys and raw pointer action. Might as well get some asm happening.